# How do you edit medication information in Apple Health on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, health.app

I have entered a medication in the Health app on my iPhone (iOS 16.4.1).

I would like to change the entry in one of 3 cases.

1. I take  medicine for Hay Fever for 3 months in the year. How do I make it As Needed for the rest of the year and a Required Daily for those 3 months?
2. I misentered data either the name of the dosage - How do I correct the error?

Archiving and re-entering is not a solution as that then means the data is not all visible on one chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the schedule by navigating in Health app to the Medications view, then tapping the relevant medicine and clicking "Edit" by Schedule.

It doesn't appear you can edit the dosage or name, however you can edit the display name by scrolling down to Details on the medicine view and tapping "Edit". You can also edit the icon.